# significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable not working on iOS 4

Tags: ios4, location, monitoring, cllocationmanager

I have the following simple code which looks if the device has a support for significant Location Change Monitoring:

```
if (![CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable])
{UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Your device won't support the significant location change." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    return;                                   
}
```

This always returns yes on iOS 5 device but returns NO on iOS 4.3 device. The devices have 3G in it.

This API is supported from 4.0 as per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is supported, but the feature isn't supported until iOS 5 and above.